# Undefined method when updating boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently working on a todo app manager.

My task model have a description and a boolean, which is false by default. 
When clicking on 'done', the boolean should switch to true.

However, I have the error `` undefined local variable or method `tasks' ``

Here's my task controller :

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.all
  @task = Task.new
end
def complete
  @task = tasks.find(params[:id])
  @task.completed = true
  @task.save
  redirect_to root_path
end

def incomplete 
  @task = tasks.find(params[:id])
  @task.completed = false
  @task.save
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

and my index :

```
<h3>Tâches à réaliser</h3>
<% @tasks.incomplete.each do |task| %>
  <p><%= "#{task.description} |  Créé le #{task.created_at.day}/#{task.created_at.month}" %>
  <%= link_to "Done", complete_task_path(task), method: :put %><%= link_to ' Modifier', edit_task_path(task) %><%= link_to ' X', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
<% end %>

<h3>Tâches réalisées</h3>
<% @tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
  <p><%= task.description %>|
  <%= link_to "Undo", incomplete_task_path(task), method: :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

and my routes :

```
resources :tasks
root 'tasks#index'

match '/tasks/complete/:id' => 'tasks#complete', as: 'complete_task', via: :put
match '/tasks/complete/:id' => 'tasks#incomplete', as: 'incomplete_task', via: :delete
```

I've tried to change variables but this error is still the same.

Does anyone know what's wrong in here ?

Answer (score 2):

The error here is pretty explicit: you're calling amethod or variable that wasn't defined.

Look at the first line in your `complete` and `incomplete` methods:

```
@task = tasks.find(params[:id])
```

`tasks` wasn't defined anywhere, hence the error. The `#find` method is, in ActiveRecord, a class method, so what you want to do is

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Or maybe they meant `@tasks`.

Comment: Indeed ... now you've said it. Thanks, I think it would have been something deeper.
And your solution works well.